# How can I let my clients use their own SSL on my SaaS

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, sni, saas, multi-tenancy

We run a service that lets our clients run their own CMS. Our clients want to use their own SSL Certificate, wether it's self signed, or signed by another company.

Our application runs `PHP`. I was thinking of a reverse proxy technology, but we have too many of them to manually reload `nginx`.

- We run on `gcloud`, so we have the ability to have buckets of SSL certificates.
- We are ready to use `SNI`, thus, dropping support for `WinXP`.
- We need to accept SSL certificates and implement them with very minimal infrastructure interaction (Reloading daemons, etc).
- We are open to using any webserver or reverse proxy technology you recommend.
- We do not want to use `UCC`, since we want to let the clients bring their own SSL.
- IPv4 is scarce, thus, we want to limit the IP addresses we choose.

How would I go on about doing this?

EDIT: I tried OpenResty with their ssl plugin, although performance is lacking. If anyone have a better idea, share!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare lets you do this with their SSL for SaaS product:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/ssl-for-saas/uploading-certificates